# Error using ColdFusion cfexchangeconnection to connect to Exchange server

Tags: coldfusion, exchange-server

I am getting an error when trying to connect to an Exchange server using the cfexchangeconnection tag.  First some code:

```
<cfexchangeconnection action="open" 
    server="****"   
    username="****" 
    password="****"
    connection="myEX" 
    protocol="https"
    port="443">
```

I know its the right server because it fails when not processing via https.  I have tried:

- Following all the instructions here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec14f31-7fed.html
- Prefixing username with a domain name, adding @domain name, etc and no luck.

The error I get is:

```
**Access to the Exchange server denied.**

Ensure that the user name and password are correct.
```

Any ideas

Comment: Can you telnet to the server? Has the Exchange server been set up to allow web access?

Comment: Yes, I can both connect via telnet and access the web version.

Comment: Did you run the keytool to import the SSL certificate used on Exchange into your keystore?

Comment: Yes.  Though is there an easy way to check if it works?

Comment: Yes. You can check the keytool by doing a CFHTTP pull from your Exchange page (you will have to use the username and password) here as well.

You can also look into the cacert file to see if the certificate is listed.  Check to make sure the JVM Coldfusion is pointed to has this cacerts file in  its : jre\lib\security

Comment: Are you using 'Forms Based Authentication'?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Re: cfhttp.  I've checked the certificate is in the keystore but cfhttp <cfhttp url="***" 
 port="443" 
 username="***" 
 password="***">
</cfhttp>

returns as a header:
"HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Content-Type: text/html Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2009 22:16:55 GMT WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate WWW-Authenticate: NTLM Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 Content-Length: 83 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET"

Dan -- I've tried setting Forms Based Authentication to both true and false but get the same result.

Comment: Use this awesome administrator plugin to view your certificates: http://certman.riaforge.org/

Comment: @Anthony -- Thanks for the link.  Certman is a great plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea - this is what I needed to do to make my cfexchange connection work. Not entirely sure if it's the same problem. I *think* I had a 440 error, rather than your 401 error.

I'm using:

- https
- webdav
- forms based auth
- Exchange 2007
- Coldfusion 8
- Windows 2003 servers

Here's the connection string that worked for me. What was keeping my connection from working was the need for the formBasedAuthenticationURL. This is a poorly documented attribute by both Adobe and Microsoft.

```
<cfexchangeconnection action="open"
 username="first.last"
 password="mypassword"
 mailboxname="myAcctName"
 server="my.mail.server"
 protocol="https"
 connection="sample"
 formBasedAuthentication="true"
 formBasedAuthenticationURL="https://my.mail.server/owa/auth/owaauth.dll">

    <cfexchangecalendar action="get" name="mycal" connection="sample">
        <cfexchangefilter name="startTime" from="#theDate#" to="#theEndDate#">
    </cfexchangecalendar>

<cfexchangeConnection action="close" connection="sample">
```

Additional notes:

- IIS and WebDAV are enabled on the target Exchange server.
- The username and password you're using has the appropriate permissions for 
  a WebDAV connection. (I'm not the Exchange admin, so I'm not sure what they 
  are, but I think the account needs to be allowed to connect to OWA. - Please 
  correct me if I am wrong.)

Optional: (don't use if you don't have to)

- IF HTTPS is required, use the appropriate argument.
- IF Forms Based Authentication is on in Exchange 2007 (as was my case), 
  you'll have to work around it using the formBasedAuthenticationURL argument.

Not sure if that's it, but I hope it is!

Comment: @Dan Thanks.  This helped a great deal.  I definitely am not using formBasedAuthentication.  The error I get now has to do with NTLM: Failure authenticating with NTLM.  This shows up in the ColdFusion Builder console but no where else.

Comment: In that case, when you figure out what NT permissions are required, could you document that here somewhere? It seems to be poorly documented. I'm sure that full Administrator would work, but none of us want to use that if we don't have to.

Comment: Well the solution was to switch to Form Based Authentication and then use your code.  Thanks Dan.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked! This was a struggle for me as well. I'd be grateful if you update this post with any future related tech notes. :-)

Comment: (Converted from answer @user1964797) Thanks for this great post -- I just wanted to make a comment about the mailboxName field -- without it, I couldn't connect at all. The error message wasn't specific, either -- it just said it couldn't connect. So make sure you have the correct mailboxName. Mine was firstname.lastname, because that's how are email addresses are set up.

Comment: I can't get my connection to work and can't seem to get anyone's attention. This is very frustrating.  What's the latest info?